# @react-native-firebase/crashlytics App detected and we're waiting for a crash

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

@react-native-firebase/crashlytics in ios App detected and we're waiting for a crash!

I have updated with the lates  @react-native-firebase/crashlytics and below are my other versions
   "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.3.0",
   "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
   "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.3.0",
       "react": "^17.0.2",
   "react-native": "^0.67.4",
  
  
But the firebase is console is giving me the below error

I was expecting the crash report in firebase console, but it only shows me App detected and we're waiting for a crash!

Answer (score 0):

The error message "App detected and we're waiting for a crash!" means that Crashlytics has been successfully installed in your app, but it has not yet detected any crashes. This can happen if your app is not crashing, or if Crashlytics is not enabled for your app.

To make sure that Crashlytics is enabled for your app, you can check the following:

Make sure that the crashlytics_debug_enabled key in your firebase.json file is set to true.
Make sure that you have run pod install in your iOS project.
Try forcing a crash in your app by calling the crashlytics().crash() method.
If you have checked all of these things and you are still not seeing crash reports in the Firebase console, you can try the following:

Check the logs for your app to see if there are any errors related to Crashlytics.
Contact Firebase support for help.
Here are some other things to keep in mind:

Crashlytics only collects crash reports for apps that are running in debug mode. If you are running your app in release mode, you will not see any crash reports.
Crashlytics may not be able to collect crash reports for all crashes. This can happen if the crash occurs before Crashlytics has been initialized, or if the crash is caused by a third-party library that is not compatible with Crashlytics.
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: "Crashlytics only collects crash reports for apps that are running in debug mode. If you are running your app in release mode, you will not see any crash reports." This seems unlikely for a tool that is literally made to report crashes in an app as its users experience them. 

Comment: "Crashlytics only collects crash reports for apps that are running in debug mode". No it doesn't  And one thing to bear in mind is if the app is running via attachment to Xcode debugger then it won't collect anything, the app has to run independently. Also a crash doesn't get sent until next time the app runs, so after a crash the app needs to be relaunched